# React Native : How to open a specific URL with onPress function from an array of urls?

Tags: arrays, react-native, url, onpress

I have an array of urls like that:

```
 [ "https://hey.com",
   "https://yes.com",
   "https://wow.com",
      /..
 ]
```

I have the same icon but multiple times. I want each of them to redirect to its specific url when on pressed.

I tried this code but it's not working:

```
onPress=(arrayOfURL)=>{  
for (i in arrayOfURL)
{      
  this.setState({ browserOpen: true });
  WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync(JSON.stringify(arrayOfURL[i]))
  .then(() => {
        WebBrowser.dismissBrowser();
        this.setState({ browserOpen: false });
    });         
}
```

}

The code for the icon:

```
          <View >         
            <Icon
              name='sc-telegram'
              type='evilicon'
              color='black'          
              onPress={this.onPress} />
          </View>
```

Comment: Can you add the code portion where you have the icons and you call `onPress()`?

Comment: I did. Do you have a hint?

Comment: I just noticed you wrote arrayOfURI[i] and not arrayOfURL[i]. Is the browser opening or is that the problem?

Comment: No, sorry, it's just a mistake. My browser doesn't open. I think the problem is that each time I press the icon, the function loops and try to open every URL in my array

Comment: Sure it tries to open every URL, isn't that you objective?

Comment: It tries to open all urls at the same time. What I want is that when I press the icon for on specific image, it opens the url for that image.

Answer (score 0):

A quick help ! Have not tested the code, but this is what i do.

```
const urls = ["https://hey.com", "https://yes.com", "https://wow.com"];

urls.map(value => {
 return <View>         
            <Icon
              name='sc-telegram'
              type='evilicon'
              color='black'          
              onPress={() => this.openSpecificUrl(value)} />
          </View>

})

onSpecificUrl = (specificUrl) => {
  //you will get specific url from an array. You can perform your opening logic here
}
```

Comment: I tried. I got 'undefined is not a function ..near urls.map..'

Answer (score 0):

So it seems you're doing a logic error. You don't need a for loop, just call onPress() method by each icon passing it a parameter that specifies the link you want to be opened:

```
<Icon
     name='sc-telegram'
     type='evilicon'
     color='black'          
     onPress={() => this.onPress(arrayOfURL[0])} />
```

And then simply:

```
onPress = (url) => {
  [...]
  WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync(url).then(...)
  [...]
}
```

If your problem is how to assign your link to icons dynamically...well that's just an other question. I hope I haven't misunderstood everything this time and that this can helps you solve your doubts.

Comment: you nailed it. my big problem is to assign dynamically, cause I have just one icon but multiple times, so I can't call onPress like `onPress={() => this.onPress(arrayOfURL[0])} />`

Comment: So, I think @Neel answer is correct. Once you've defined your array of urls, map it with its correct name in the render method (where you have to place your icons).